# Neo4j - Match multiple Nodes using IDs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to retrieve multiple nodes in Neo4j and I only have there IDs.

Is there a way to retrieve nodes that have their ID in the given set in one cypher query ? Or do I have to call the db for each ID ?

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.5

Thanks !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can match within an Array.

```
MATCH (u:`User`) WHERE ID(u) IN [1, 2, 3] RETURN u
```

Comment: For completeness, you can also use `START n=node(1, 2, 3) RETURN n;`. However, `START` is being deprecated, so avoid this.

Comment: Hey @cybersam, `START` is being deprecated?  Can you describe a bit more?  I know it's far less used recently, but is there any identified fix on how people will refer to legacy indexes without `START`?   (I'd love to see it go away, just want to understand how the language will change)

Comment: See, for example, the `Important` note at the top of this page: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-start.html

Comment: It's because they're trying to get everyone to stop using the DB IDs in their queries. It's recommended that you generate unique IDs in your app.

Comment: @subvertallchris how would you write this in neo4j.rb?